# __name__ field of class construed using type() function

Tags: python, class

Why does the `__name__` field have two values as in the following code?

```
cls = type('A',(object,),{'__name__':'not_A'})

cls.__dict__['__name__']
```

this gives `'not_A'`

```
cls.__name__
```

this gives

```
'A'
```

why the two are different?

Comment: ```cls.__name__``` refers to an attribute of ```cls```. ```cls.__dict__['__name__']``` refers to the value of key ```__name__``` in attribute ```__dict__```. They are not referring to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The `type` class, of which `cls` is an instance, has an attribute `__name__` which is some sort of descriptor:

```
>>> type.__dict__['__name__']
<attribute '__name__' of 'type' objects>
>>> type(_)
<class 'getset_descriptor'>
```

When you try access an actual instance attribute on `cls` by the same name, the `getset_descriptor` takes precedence, so that the only way to access the instant attribute is directly, via `cls.__dict__`.